Multiple AsyncStreams Failing in Swift
I am following a tutorial and trying to listen to Presence and Channel Stream in Supabase. The problem is that I can only listen to one of them. If I put for await with presenceStream first then it works but the changeStream is never fired and vice versa. How can I listen to both the streams using AsyncStream.
Do I have to wrap both of them in Task closure?
 func configureChannelSubscription() async throws {
        
        let channel = supabaseClient.channel("general")
        let presenceStream = channel.presenceChange()
        
        let changeStream = channel.postgresChange(
            AnyAction.self,
            schema: "public",
            table: "chats"
        )
        
        let userStatus = UserStatus(username: "johndoe", online: true)
        
        await channel.subscribe()
        
        try await channel.track(userStatus)
        
        for await presence in presenceStream {
            print("presence")
            print(presence.joins) // You can also use presence.decodeJoins(as: MyType.self)
            print(presence.leaves) // You can also use presence.decodeLeaves(as: MyType.self)
        }
        
        for await change in changeStream {
            switch change {
                case .delete(let action): print("Deleted: \(action.oldRecord)")
                case .insert(let action):
                    await handleInsertChat(action.record)
                case .select(let action): print("Selected: \(action.record)")
                case .update(let action): print("Updated: \(action.record)")
            }
        }
    }


When should configureChannelSubscription return? Should it return after both streams have been fully consumed?

Create group and listen in group tasks

You don't need to wrap them in Tasks. Since the for await loops don't seem to produce any value and appears to just go on forever, you can use a discarding task group,
await withDiscardingTaskGroup { group in
    group.addTask {
        for await presence in presenceStream {
            // ...
        }
    }
    group.addTask {
        for await change in changeStream {
            // ...
        }
    }
}

Or use withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) for below iOS 17.
Note that configureChannelSubscription will not return until the for await loops finish. If you want it to return right after channel.track(userStatus) finishes, you should wrap withDiscardingTaskGroup in a Task, and assign it to some property so you can cancel it later if needed.
